# Android NDK VERY long build times

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build a NativeActivity project under windows using eclipse and the android NDK.

It is taking extremely long to build. Building it on linux takes only a couple min, but on windows it takes 30 min.

Is there some bug and work around to this extremely long compile time?

I have set the flag LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=true in android.mk to fix a linker error I was getting.

Comment: Have you tried building it from the Windows command line using the multithreaded option (e.g. -j8)? NDK-BUILD -j8

Comment: Other GCC-based toolchains do tend to be substantially slower on Windows due to some workarounds for unsupported unix paradigms.

Comment: If I want to compile using build project in eclipse, is there a way I can add it so it uses -j 4? I add it to cpp_flags in application.mk, and then I get the error "-j is a recognized command"

Comment: What NDK version are you using?  The causes full rebuild issue should have been fixed long ago. It would seem like increasing your environment size might fix the fundamental windows issue you are trying to work around.  Realistically though, save yourself a lot of headache with a 2nd rate compilation environment by switching to Linux or OSX for NDK work.

Comment: I am using ndk version 9d. The latest I believe.

Comment: How do I increase environment size?

Comment: Ever found a workaround for this issue?  I am facing a similar problem.